# pyinstaller created executable deletes itself upon running

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, pyinstaller

I'm using pyinstaller to make an macos app out of a .py file using tkinter to build a GUI, and every time I build it and go into the dist/programname directory and try running the programname executable, it spits the following out at me before deleting/removing the executable:

```
myname@C02F508MML7L ~ % /Users/username/Documents/dist/programname/programname ; exit;
zsh: killed     /Users/username/Documents/dist/programname/programname

Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

I'm not positive what's causing this? I've used almost the same code without tkinter to create an executable and it worked just fine